# Monte Carlo integration with imposed variance

Tags: self-study, simulation, monte-carlo, importance-sampling

> Implement an estimator using Monte Carlo integration of the quantity
>   $$\theta=\int_0^1e^{-x^2}(1-x)dx$$ Estimate $\theta$ with a variance
>   lower than $10^{-4}$ by writing the variance of this estimator depending on
>   sample size.

We can write 
$$\theta=\int \phi(x)f(x)dx$$
where $\phi(x)$ is a function and $f(x)$ is a density so that $$\phi(x)f(x)=e^{-x^2}(1-x)\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(x)$$ The exercise leaves open the choice of the density.
Thus the estimator has the form $$\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \phi(x_i)$$
The exercise asks for an estimate of $\theta$ with variance lower than $0.0001$ by expressing the variance of the estimator as a function of n.

Comment: What's wrong with just increasing $n$ to 10^7? That seems to do it.

Comment: @philchalmers But how can I write the variance of my estimator in terms of n?

Comment: You have the variance estimator given $n$ already in your answer. MC integration error is root-n consistent, so the variance decreases to 0 at a rate of 1/$n$.

Comment: you seem to have a typo for the line `X = (exp(1)^(-U^2)*(1-U))`: it'll be equal to `(1 - U)`

Comment: This appears to be just another version of your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151224/double-integral-monte-carlo-estimation, which also asks how to perform a MC integration with a given estimation variance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that without knowing exactly what $\theta$ is, we cannot know the variance of its Monte-Carlo estimator.  The solution is to *estimate* that variance and hope the estimate is sufficiently close to the truth.

---

**The very simplest form of Monte-Carlo estimation** surrounds the graph of the integrand, $f(x) = e^{-x^2}(1-x)$, by a box (or other congenial figure that is easy to work with) of area $A$ and places $n$ independent uniformly random points in the box.  The proportion of points lying under the graph, times the area $A$, estimates the area $\theta$ under the graph.  As usual, let's write this estimator of $\theta$ as $\hat\theta$.  For examples, see the figure at the end of this post.

Because the chance of any point lying under the graph is $p = \theta / A$, the count $X$ of points lying under the graph has a Binomial$(n, p)$ distribution.  This has an expected value of $np$ and a variance of $np(1-p)$.  The variance of the estimate therefore is

$$\text{Var}(\hat \theta) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{AX}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{A}{n}\right)^2\text{Var}(X) = \left(\frac{A}{n}\right)^2 n \left(\frac{\theta}{A}\right)\left(1 - \frac{\theta}{A}\right) = \frac{\theta(A-\theta)}{n}.$$

Because we do no know $\theta$, we first use a small $n$ to obtain an initial estimate and plug that into this variance formula. (A good educated guess about $\theta$ will serve well to start, too. For instance, the graph (see below) suggests $\theta$ is not far from $1/2$, so you could start by substituting that for $\hat\theta$.) This is the *estimated variance*,

$$\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat\theta) = \frac{\hat\theta(A-\hat\theta)}{n}.$$

Using this initial estimate $\hat\theta$, find an $n$ for which $\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat\theta) \le 0.0001 = T$.  The smallest possible such $n$ is easily found, with a little algebraic manipulation of the preceding formula, to be

$$\hat n = \bigg\lceil\frac{\hat\theta(A - \hat\theta)}{T}\bigg\rceil.$$

Iterating this procedure eventually produces a sample size that will at least approximately meet the variance target.  As a practical matter, at each step $\hat n$ should be made sufficiently greater than the previous estimate of $n$ so that eventually a large enough $n$ is guaranteed to be found for which $\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat\theta)$ is sufficiently small.  For instance, if $\hat n$ is less than twice the preceding estimate, use twice the preceding estimate instead.

---

**In the example in the question,** because $f$ ranges from $1$ down to $0$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, we may surround its graph by a box of height $1$ and width $1$, whence $A=1$.

One calculation beginning at $n=10$ first estimated the variance as $2/125$, resulting in a guess $\hat n = 1600$.  Using $1600$ new points (I didn't even bother to recycle the original $10$ points) resulted in an updated estimated variance of $0.0001545$, which was still too large.  It suggested using $\hat n = 2473$ points.  The calculation terminated there with $\hat\theta = 0.4262$ and $\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat\theta) = 0.00009889$, just less than the target of $0.0001$.  The figure shows the random points used at each of these three stages, from left to right, superimposed on plots of the box and the graph of $f$.

[image: Figure]

Since the true value is $\theta = 0.430764\ldots$, the true variance with $n=2473$ is $\theta(1-\theta)/n = 0.00009915\ldots$. (Another way to express this is to observe that $n=2453$ is the smallest number for which the true variance is less than $0.0001$, so that using the estimated variance in place of the true variance has cost us an extra $20$ sample points.)

In general, when the area under the graph $\theta$ is a sizable fraction of the box area $A$, the estimated variance will not change much when $\theta$ changes, so it's usually the case that the estimated variance is accurate.  When $\theta/A$ is small, a better (more efficient) form of Monte-Carlo estimation is advisable.

Comment: That you did is "Hit or Miss"?

Comment: So you're … estimating the variance of the estimate?  So the variance has a variance?

Comment: @endolith That is correct.

Comment: "Let's write this as $\hat\theta$." Does $\hat\theta$ = "The proportion of points lying under the graph, times the area A" or just "The [number] of points lying under the graph"?  "this" is ambiguous, but I think you mean the latter

Comment: @endolith Thank you--that is indeed ambiguous within the context of the immediately preceding sentence.  I'll fix it.  The convention of putting a hat on an estimator of a quantity, though, rescues the notation from that ambiguity.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> Implement an estimator using Monte Carlo integration of
>   $$\theta=\int\limits_0^1e^{-x^2}(1-x)dx$$

While you can use a $\mathcal{U}([0,1])$ distribution for your Monte Carlo experiment, the fact that both $$x \longrightarrow \exp\{-x^2\}\quad \text{and}\quad x \longrightarrow (1-x)$$ are decreasing functions suggest that a decreasing density would work better. For instance, a *truncated* Normal $\mathcal{N}^1_0(0,.5)$ distribution could be used:
\begin{align*}\theta&=\int\limits_0^1e^{-x^2}(1-x)\,\text{d}x\\&=[\Phi(\sqrt{2})-\Phi(0)]\sqrt{2\pi\frac{1}{2}}\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{\Phi(\sqrt{2})-\Phi(0)}\dfrac{e^{-x^2/2\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\frac{1}{2}}}(1-x)\,\text{d}x\\&=[\Phi(\sqrt{2})-\Phi(0)]\sqrt{\pi}\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{\Phi(\sqrt{2})-\Phi(0)}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}(1-x)\,\text{d}x\end{align*}
which leads to the implementation

```
n=1e8
U=runif(n)
#inverse cdf simulation
X=qnorm(U*pnorm(sqrt(2))+(1-U)*pnorm(0))/sqrt(2)
X=(pnorm(sqrt(2))-pnorm(0))*sqrt(pi)*(1-X)
mean(X)
sqrt(var(X)/n)
```

with the result

```
>     mean(X)
[1] 0.4307648
>     sqrt(var(X)/n)
[1] 2.039857e-05
```

fairly close to the true value

```
> integrate(function(x) exp(-x^2)*(1-x),0,1)
0.4307639 with absolute error < 4.8e-15
```

Another representation of the same integral is to use instead the distribution with density$$f(x)=2(1-x)\mathbb{I}{[0,1]}(x)$$and cdf $F(x)=1-(1-x)^2$ over $[0,1]$. The associated estimation is derived as follows:

```
> x=exp(-sqrt(runif(n))^2)/2
> mean(x)
[1] 0.4307693
> sqrt(var(x)/n)
[1] 7.369741e-06
```

which does better than the truncated normal simulation.

Comment: You have chosen the normal distribution, but the distribution support has to be compatible with the limits of integration? Or the support may be different since it encompasses the integration range?To write the variance in function of n, I can simply do $\sigma^2/n$ where $\sigma^2$ is the value of variance?

Comment: I used a _truncated_ Normal for this purpose. Hence the normalising constant with $\Phi(1)-\Phi(0)$.

Comment: One more thing, if I could only generate $10^4$ random variables, It would be impossible to achieve that certain variance? Even by applying any variance reduction technique right?

Comment: It is _always_ possible to find a smaller variance estimator, by using an appropriately different importance sampling distribution. The only limit is zero.

Comment: Why the variance is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt(n)}$ and not $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$?

Comment: Is it possible to get an estimator such that the variance be  $\frac{c}{n}$ where c<0.0001?What I mean is that the estimator of variance is <0.0001 independent of sample size?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean

Comment: The question itself appears to focus on how to find an appropriate value of $n$.  Why did you chose $10^8$?

Comment: @whuber: (+1) for your answer which addresses the second part of the question. I used `1e8` only to follow suit from earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether "write the variance of estimator" means to write the equation or the results of the execution. If the latter is the case then all you need to do is to run your code at different $n$ and show how the variance shrinks with $n$.

If the former is the case, then you have to show the equation for the variance estimate of the Monte Carlo algorithm.

Comment: In reality it is to do both.

Comment: In this case show the estimate of the variance using MC convergence theorems. Those are usually based on some form of central limit theorem application.